# laravel update a uique value validation

Tags: php, validation, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a model with a `mobileNumber` property. the mobile number is unique and the validation rules are:

```
public  static  $rulesForEdit = array(
        'firstName' => 'required|min:5',
        'lastName' => 'required|min:5',
        'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:5|unique:admin,mobileNumber|numeric'
    );
```

when I update the model, I do this:

```
$data = array('firstName' => Input::get('firstName'),
        'lastName' => Input::get('lastName'),
        'mobileNumber' => Input::get('mobileNumber')
);
$validation = Validator::make($data, Admin::$rulesForEdit);
if($validation->passes()){
    $admin = Admin::find($id);
    $admin->firstName = Input::get('firstName');
    $admin->lastName = Input::get('lastName');
    $admin->mobileNumber = Input::get('mobileNumber');
    $admin->update();
    return Redirect::to("restaurants/admins/".$admin->id);
}else{

    return Redirect::back()->withInput()->withErrors($validation);
}
```

The problem that I keep getting a validation error message  states that : `The mobile number has already been taken`, **which is correct**, but the mobile is belongs to the same model that I am updating, there is no other model that took this mobile number, just the one that I want to update. **In other words, I am updating the firstname and the last name but not the mobile number,**

Comment: As per your condition in the  table `admin` `mobileNumber` shold be unique ie no duplication is allowed , if your not updating the mobile number remove it from the validation

Comment: @VijayaragavendranHariharan it is unique in my table too.

Comment: '$data = array('firstName' => Input::get('firstName'),
        'lastName' => Input::get('lastName'),
  
);


`$admin = Admin::find($id);
    $admin->firstName = Input::get('firstName');
    $admin->lastName = Input::get('lastName');
    $admin->update();`

if you not going to update it then no need of validation rite ?

Comment: @VijayaragavendranHariharan maybe the user updates the mobile? it is working when he update the mobile with a new mobile that hasn't been used before, but it is not working when he doesn't change the current mobile number. got me please?

Comment: yes i got whats  the problem is

Comment: you should rewrite the validation rule like
`'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:5|unique:admin,mobileNumber,' . $id`

To force the validator to ignore unique rule for a given id you may pass the id of that recored which is being validated,

Comment: @VijayaragavendranHariharan so the new rule should be this `'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:5|unique:admin,mobileNumber,.$id|numeric'` ?

Comment: 'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:5|numeric|unique:admin,mobileNumber,' . $id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To force the Validator to ignore unique rule for a given id you may pass the id of that recored which is being validated, for example:

```
'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:5|numeric|unique:admin,mobileNumber,50'
```

This, will not check uniqueness of the model if the id is 10, so when you are updating the model you need to pass the id of the current model to ignore the unique rule on this model:

```
'mobileNumber' => 'required|min:5|numeric|unique:admin,mobileNumber,' . $id


// Replace the Model with the name of your model within the controller 
// update method before the validation takes place 
Model::$rules['mobileNumber'] = 'required|min:5|numeric|unique:admin,mobileNumber,' . $id;
```

Comment: why did you remove the `numeric` ?

Comment: I have added the numeric too

Comment: there is a syntax error, I can't say `. $id` in my rules. The rules array is in the `Admin` model and it is static array

Comment: // Replace the Model with the name of your model within the controller
// update method before the validation takes place
Model::$rules['mobileNumber'] = 'required|min:5|numeric|unique:admin,mobileNumber,' . $id;